# Can't pipe a string (with xml text) in NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, proxy, stream, buffer

I have this code:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + 
           '<root>' +
               '<child foo="bar">' +
                   '<grandchild baz="fizbuzz">grandchild content</grandchild>' +
               '</child>' +
               '<sibling>with content!</sibling>' +
           '</root>';

    var objStream = through2({
      objectMode: true
    },function (chunk, enc, callback) {
      // I don't want this chunk.... I need to pass the xml string....
      var chunk = chunk.toString();
      this.push(chunk);
      callback();
    });

    var buf = req.pipe(objStream).pipe(buffr()); 

})
```

All I need is to pass to pipe the xml string I declared before....
Something like:

```
this.push(xml);
```

But obviously it doesn't work and I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you,mscdex for your correction. But I still with the same problem....

Comment: If you don't need `chunk`, why are you streaming the request in the first place? Seems like this task could be achieved with a much simpler HTTP handler.

Comment: Good question. I need to stream request for this statement: proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://localhost:9953',buffer:buf}); where I need to pass the buf.... But this buf need to have the 'chunk modified' by the xml variable I declared before....

Comment: To be exact, I will need to transform the original chunk to build a "new data". But I don't understand the mechanism to pass a transformed data and I don't know how to manipulate this chunk, for example, adding a new tag or something like that...

Comment: If that is the case, then I don't see what is not working. `through` and `through2` are both wrappers for the node.js Transform stream, which transforms the data from a ReadStream before passing it to a WriteStream. You just need to interpolate the data from "chunk" with your XML template. You could even use a templating engine like Lodash or Mustache for this. Then you can just call `this.push()` with the newly made XML string.

Comment: Thank you,  djfdev! Do you have any code to template XML? Using this.push(xml) is not working......

Comment: Sure ... here's a quick gist I made. It creates a file stream from a text file that is a list of names and compiles each name in an XML template https://gist.github.com/djfdev/1ed4aa01ecd571bf9279

Comment: Thank you, djfdev! One question, it fails when I execute var template = _.template('<%= name %>'); trying to remove the <name> label. ow to sort it out? I only need to pass the template I have, without any additional tags.... Thank you!

Comment: Then just use your template rather than the example I provided. Read the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#template) on templating for more information.

Comment: hmmmm.... Really cool library loadash! But I tried with a lot of options but I could not pipe it wiithout the tag: <name><%= name %></name>. According to the loadash docs it should work with <%= name %>, indeed I can print it but I can't pipe it. Did you have some experience with piping the text wihtout having to stream it from file? Again, thanks for your help!